# QT: Creating multiple rows in a UI dependent on a variable (quantity of rows)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I've coded a UI in QT with PySide that looks like the following:

```
-Text field- -file browser button-
                 - ok button -
```

Now I have a variable e.g. i=3 that is defined by a user beforehand. What I'd like to have now is that my UI should transform dynamically i.e.

```
-Text field- -file browser button-
-Text field- -file browser button-
-Text field- -file browser button-
                 - ok button -
```

So basically that i get i rows. When the user has entered every text field and has clicked every file browser button, I want to store all of the information in a list with tuples, i.e. ((name1,dir1), (name2,dir2), ...).
This is my code till now:

```
class SelectFiles(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Data Analysis - File selection')
        self.setMinimumWidth(400)
        self.mainlayout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Create the QHBoxLayout that lays out the whole form
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()

        # Create line for Names
        self.Name1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.Name1.setPlaceholderText('Name')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Name1)

        # Create the build button with its caption
        self.build_button = QPushButton('Select File', self)
        # Add it to the button box
        self.layout.addWidget(self.build_button)

        # Connect the button's clicked signal to ReadFileInput
        self.build_button.clicked.connect(self.readfileinput)

        #
        self.mainlayout.addLayout(self.layout)

        # Set the VBox layout as the window's main layout
        self.setLayout(self.mainlayout)

        # Create a horizontal box layout to hold the button
        self.button_box = QHBoxLayout()

        # Add stretch to push the button to the far right
        self.button_box.addStretch(1)

        # Create the build button with its caption
        self.build_buttonOK = QPushButton('Ok', self)

        # Connect the button's clicked signal to ReadInput
        self.build_buttonOK.clicked.connect(self.readnameinputs)

        # Add it to the button box
        self.button_box.addWidget(self.build_buttonOK)

        # Add the button box to the bottom of the main VBox layout
        self.mainlayout.addLayout(self.button_box)

    @Slot()
    def readfileinput(self):
        global fileselect1
        fileselect1 = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)[0]

    @Slot()
    def readnameinputs(self):
        Name = self.Name1.text()

        lists.append((Name, fileselect1))

        qt_app.quit()


    def run(self):
        # Show the form
        self.show()
        # Run the qt application
        qt_app.exec_()

# Classes

qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)

lists = []

app2 = SelectFiles()
app2.run()
```

Now, I'm not a professional programmer and intuitively I'd have tried something like

```
for j in range(i):
    self.layout + i = QHBoxLayout()
    self.Name + i = QLineEdit(self)
```

etc., of course that's not possible in Python (-> defining variables with variables that are looped over). Now I have no idea how I could do this easily. Does anybody know?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list to hold your widgets which you initialize in the `init` function:

```
self.input_lines = []
```

I also recommend to use a QGridLayout instead of QHBoxLayouts so that you only need a single layout. The for loop could then look like this:

```
for j in range(i):
    text_field = QLineEdit()
    browser = QPushButton()
    self.input_lines.append((text_field, browser))
    self.grid_layout.addWidget(j, 0, text_field)
    self.grid_layout.addWidget(j, 1, browser)
```

A text field would then be accessed with `self.input_lines[index][0]`.

**EDIT (adding information from comments)**

To connect the buttons' `clicked` signals to different slots in a for loop, lambda expressions can be used:

```
for j in range(i):
    self.input_lines[j][1].clicked.connect(lambda row=j: self.readfileinput(row))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have an idea how I could now connect the buttons to getOpenFileName, so that I can store the dirs of the data that the user chooses? I've tried looping over a variable k with self.input_lines[k][1].clicked.connect(self.readfileinput()), but of course the readfileinput function needs to behave differently dependent on k, such that not every button does the same when clicked. I've tried to change my definition to def readfileinput(self, k) and loop over .connect.(self.readfileinput(k)) but somehow that doesn't work.

Comment: I think this can be solved with a lambda: `self.input_lines[k][1].clicked.connect(lambda : self.readfileinput(k))`. The clicked signal is connected to a lambda in which `readfileinput` is called with the correct index.

Comment: Actually I also found this after my answer thanks to google, at first it looked good, but then i realized, that no matter which button i press k is always the maximal value (i.e. if i=5 -> k_max=4 (0,1,2,3,4)):`for k in range(len(self.input_lines)):
            self.input_lines[k][1].clicked.connect(lambda: self.readfileinput(k))
def readfileinput(self, k): print k `
However it should rather be "press button 1" -> k=0

Comment: I guess the problem with the lambda function is the loop, because `.connect(lambda : self.readfileinput(k))` is actually the same as `def readfile(): return self.readfileinput(k) ; .connect(readfile)`. This doesn't work with a loop, because the definition for the function without arguments gets written over with every k, such that k is always maximally in the print.

Comment: I have found the solution, it works if you just do `.connect(lambda k=k: self.readfileinput(k))`

Comment: Good to know! I didn't even know this syntax existed. I will add it to the answer for the future.